# Tab content is the same after clicking the tab containing sharepoint page

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying add tabs to my app in microsoft-teams.

The problem is that when I click on the onboarding tab, then click on the my organization tab (which contains the sharepoint content), and then click on the home tab, the content will be the same as the content on the onboarding tab. So the problem appears after clicking the my organization tab (which contains sharepoint content).
even though the url I entered to fill the tab in the app studio is correct.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBnXV.jpg
How do I make the content appear according to the clicked tab?

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the manifest json, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: Hi @Sayali-MSFT , 
this is my manifest json [link](https://pastebin.com/AnkhVPY9)

Comment: I am tried to repro, but it's working fine from our end. Could you please check it once?[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgADL.png
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/garsT.png

Comment: @sitifatimah-Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT but when I try to still have the same problem, is it because of the sharepoint link I'm using? Does that have an effect?

Comment: @sitifatimah- No. I am also using the sharepoint link for onboarding tab.

Comment: @sitifatimah-Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?